# SSRS - List with dynamic items - prevent hidden items from taking space

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL 2008 R2 SSRS report - works great MUCH of the time, but depending on the rules of a specific customer, it may not look beautiful.

It has a list in it - and the rules may specific that items within the list should be shown or not shown. There is one query, which returns one row, and if at all possible, I'd like to leave it at one query for performance reasons.

So for example, we have a list that has:

```
-- Section A
   \- Item 1      |     Item 2

-- Section B
   \- Item 1   |  Item 1a
      Item 2   |  Item 3

-- Section C
   \- Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4
      Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7 | Item 8
```

Based on rules, though, I need to hide and "collapse" Section B, so that Section C rolls up right underneath of Section A. Or perhaps Section A will be collapsed.

I know that if I had the ability to make this a matrix, I could dynamically hide rows, but I can't make it a matrix without a massive reconfiguration of the query.

Any thoughts how I could accomplish hiding sections, or hiding lists, and making next list, or section, come up right beneath the previous visible section or list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could put section B inside of a rectangle in the list and conditionally hide the rectangle. Just make sure that Section A and Section C are flush with the top and bottom of the rectangle that will be conditionally hidden.
Or if Section B is just another iteration of the list then you could add a filter that will make it not show that iteration.